# What is the infinite sum of This alternating series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have encountered this alternating series and I want to know how we can prove that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{n^{3}+1}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{3}\sinh\left(\pi\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Can you prove the converse using Taylor Expansion?

Comment: Even better, can you give us some context, or some of your own thoughts about the problem? See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask